# HTML page stuck on loading while using python cgi to run linux command

Tags: python, html, linux, cgi

I am using the following code to create a virtual machine on kvm...
it works perfectly but.... my html page is stuck at loading since the command for creating virtual machine is running...
after 1 or 2 seconds, the job of this command is done...
then i want to go to next page
but it is still loading
please help

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi
import commands

print "Content-type:text/html"
print ""

cmd = "sudo virt-install --cdrom /iso/win7.iso --ram 1024 --vcpu 1 --disk 30 --name wind7 --graphics vnc,listen=127.0.0.1,port=5912,password=123"

output=commands.getoutput(cmd)
print "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://127.0.0.1/abc.html'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start your command in the background so that Python can proceed with the next line without waiting for `sudo virt-install` to terminate.

Instead of `commands`, use the module `os`:

```
import os
os.spawnl(os.P_DETACH, 'cmd')
```

If this doesn't work, try `P_NOWAIT` instead of `P_DETACH`.

Note: you might need to delay the redirect by a few seconds, so that the mount has enough time to do the job before the browser tries to open the HTML page.

Comment: Yeah, you probably need to find out how to pass the arguments to `spawnl` properly: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.spawnl

Comment: Alternatively, try `subprocess` instead of `os`.